# Female-female connector, but what is it called?

Tags: pcb, components, connector

#### Question

What is the "official" name for this type of connector? (the large black box in the image)

#### More info...

I need the connection to connect two PCBs together as one was missing from a system that I purchased.

The connection links between the **male** header pins on **two** circuit boards and therefore needs to be **female-female**.

After an extensive search on-line I've come to the conclusion that without knowing what it is called I'm not going to be able to find them.

[image: Diagram of connection]

Comment: I've seen them called "gender-bender" but I'm not going to recommend that as a search term!

Comment: Gender-benders, turn-arounds, <insert connector> female-to-female, and plenty of other terms not suitable for polite company...

Comment: When doing this, take care to make sure your connector pin-outs do not become mirror-imaged. You could consider fabricating your own with IDC ribbon-cable connectors.

Comment: I'm not sure I've ever seen these so they might not be all that common and I couldn't see anything similar at a few suppliers. If you can't locate them raised female PCB mount connectors of varying heights are common and you could solder a couple back-to-back and use epoxy to firmly secure them.

Comment: @PeterJ These types of connectors are most common in A/V and event production where multiple systems need to be integrated together, generally in somewhat creative ways.

Comment: It's a double female connector.

Comment: "Non-standard".

Comment: @MattYoung this one specifically is being used inside of a control panel -  with limited space - where the two boards sit one on top of the other.

Comment: @PeterJ See comment above for application. Also, I thought about soldering female headers back-to-back or using crimps with a short about of wire. But it didn't seem as elegant. In the end I managed to salvage the part (although not a perfect fit) from the old system.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the help! I have fixed the problem using parts (although not the *correct* parts) from the old system. I haven't yet been able to find the **female** *gender benders* as yet (although I did find male-male ones) - guess I'll keep an eye out for them! Anyway, now to go clean up my search history....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are officially called **Gender Changers**  but they are commonly referred to as GenderBenders (which may or may not be PC these days...)

Comment: I haven't been able to find female-female ones yet (only male-male :( ) but everyone seems to be in agreement that this is the right terminology so thanks anyway!